# unable to get the public ip in swift ios or mac os

Tags: ios, swift

How can I get public IP address of mobile or mac using swift without using third party URLs.

Can anyone help and also I have tried the apple `portmapper.h` class but it is returning `nil`.

```
let data = PortMapper.findPublicAddress()
print(data)
```

Showing `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

In most networks, the device a user is using rarely has a public IP... there will be a router or firewall etc and that might have a public IP or it might route through another device which has a public IP.

The reason for using a third party is because that third party would only be able to see the public IP that’s the devices network is using to reach them so you know it’s the correct IP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187426/can-i-know-how-to-detect-the-screen-sharing-is-running-or-not-in-mac